# Having trouble downloading ADT plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've tried to get into Android developent, and here's how the Android site says to get the ADT plugin for Eclipse:

*If Eclipse is already installed on your computer, make sure that it is a version that is compatible with ADT and the Android SDK......Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
**

The thing is, as shown in the picture, There is no Install Software button. This is the standard, latest, popular version of Java Eclipse (on Win32).

Heres what it looks like: http://i1085.photobucket.com/albums/j421/dmarquand/adt.jpg?t=1304235463

Is this the wrong version of Eclipse? If anyone has been in my shoes, please explain how you got the ADT plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: you would probably click on software updates > find and install, then you would click add button, then name it something like android and to location write the url that is required.

Comment: Thanks to my basic logic skills, I did that without luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Find and Install" option...

You want to install stuff right? Worth a try.

Comment: The find and install option did nothing, and the properties took me to a page that included things such as "Installation History" and "Scan for updates" but nowhere could I find something that looked right...

Answer (score -1):

I would try downloading [Eclipse Classic](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.2-201102101200/eclipse-SDK-3.6.2-win32.zip). This is a link to the latest 32-bit version, which is at this moment 3.6.2.